# Is it possible to define Magento layout updates on a per-store basis

Tags: magento

I have a single Magento install running two different websites. One sells ebooks and the other not and so the business team would like to see the "My Downloads" link removed from the customer navigation block in the My Account area of the application.

I can see the link defined in design/frontend/base/layout/downloadable.xml but cannot see any way defined that would let me disable the link on just one of the websites. Obviously, I could override this XML to turn off globally but I need the change to be limited in scope.

How do you define layout overrides on a single website or store in a multi site Magento installation?

Based on the responses below, I have done the following:

Created app/local/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Navigation.php and added a method removeLink() which is not in the core code.

If I make the following change in local.xml, the download link is removed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
    </default>   
    <customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="removeLink" translate="label" module="downloadable"> <name>downloadable_products</name></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
</layout>
```

But, if try to target a specific store, it is not. E.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar"/>
    </default>
    <STORE_mm>
    <customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="removeLink" translate="label" module="downloadable"> <name>downloadable_products</name></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
    </STORE_mm>
</layout>
```

Comment: if you use different themes then this is really easy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Anton suggested, set a new layout theme for your store. Another approach for anything site-wide + store-scoped would be to use the store layout handle - it's like a `<default>` handle which is applied each store. If your store code (under Manage Stores > Store View) is 'foo' the store layout handle would be `<STORE_foo>`.

Ref. `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::addActionLayoutHandles()`

Comment: I am trying to take the store-scoped approach to this and have updated the question to reflect. The two websites are very similar so having multiple themes is not ideal in this instance. However, the STORE_x rule does not seem to be processed. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The `<STORE_...>` handles are just that, handles. They do not qualify other handles; they are only usable for store-wide layout updates. Given your updated example you would need to declare a new layout theme for your `mm` store, but that entire theme will only contain the local.xml, which would need to contain all of the "global" local.xml directives. Your other option is to create a custom module which just adds a new layout file to the system and simply use that like a local.xml.

Comment: Took the separate theme approach which combined with the change to add a removeLink method works great - thx

Comment: Is there a website handle similar to store handle? (like <WEBSITE_>, but this is apparently not it)

Comment: @Daew no, but you could add this handle using an observer. Alternately, you could define a layout update and then use the `<update />` directive to include it in all store handles. Might be a pain to maintain if you have lots of stores though.

Answer (score 2):

Create different themes for this websites.
Create app/design/frontend/default/website1/layout/local.xml 
and app/design/frontend/default/website2/layout/local.xml
Where you can make changes needed for downloadable layout.
This is described in magento feature.

Comment: +1 this. I have found to be the cleanest approach to managing multiple store themes is to keep them isolated, with fallback to default for anything that affects multiple store scopes. Also recommend doing it in a separate package from default, e.g. app/design/frontend/mypackage/mytheme, and app/design/frontend/mypackage/default respectively.