# Is it possible to specify store view in layout file

Tags: xml, magento, layout

I have a store views: English, Latvian.

And i want to react to both store views calling a different template for each in one local.xml

smth like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <English>
        <!-- do stuff... -->
    </English>
    <Latvian>
        <!-- do stuff... -->
    </Latvian>
</layout>
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

A better aproach would be to create two seperate themes for the two store views. Then assign these to the store views either through `System->Design` or through `System-> Configuration-> Design->Themes`. This way you may have two `layout.xml` files and more control over the skin etc.

But if you just wanted to have seperate `layout.xml` use the `System-> Configuration-> Design->Themes->Layout` option.

Comment: yeah i know.. but if i want make only minor changes like this above 6 lines long.. i taught its useless to have two allmost axacty the same files. Another minus is - whenever im going to change the local.xml for both store views i'll need to do that in both files. so maybe there is a way to put it in one local.xml

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787089/is-it-possible-to-define-magento-layout-updates-on-a-per-store-basis

Comment: Heh, interesting to almost answer a question, read the comments on an answer, and find a link to the answer you've already given. Ref the part of [`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::addActionLayoutHandles()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L280) which adds the store-specific layout update handle for a `loadLayout()` call.